# getting the index of partial tuple in a list

Tags: scala

I want to find the index of an item in a list

```
scala> type BarType = (String,Int)
defined type alias BarType

scala> val bar:BarType =  ("A",2)
bar: BarType = (A,2)

scala> val bars = List(bar)
bars: List[BarType] = List((A,2))
```

I want to find the element that contains "A" regardless to the second item in the tuple something like

```
bars.indexOf(("A",_))
```

but this fails

```
<console>:11: error: missing parameter type for expanded function ((x$1) => scala.Tuple2("A", x$1))
              bars.indexOf(("A",_))
```

is there a straightforward way to do it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
val i = bars.indexWhere(_._1 == "A")
```